# ios filter options similar to the apple store (dropdown list)

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to figure out how to make a filter option similar to the apple store's filter options. The first thing that came to my mind are dropdownlists similar to websites. But it doesn't seem to have it on the objects options in xcode. Was wondering where should I start in order to make that kind of function.

It's similar to this

http://www.insightguides.com/docs/halo-asset-manager/images/apps/berlitz-cruise-2013-ipad-6.jpg

Unless you guys can recommend something else? Looking at this, it seems to me it's just a popover? If this is so, I am in need of 4 - 5 filters, does that mean I should create 4 - 5 viewcontrollers to popover? It seems like a lot of space is being used just for filters, not really sure how to dynamically generate it using just 1 viewcontroller.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your filters look the same but have different data then you could just have one FilterViewController and change its data source depending on the filter type.

And yes, that does look like a simple UIPopoverController.

So when you have to display a new popover create a FilterViewController and assign it the appropriate data source.  You can use delegation to inform the parent class which filter was selected and use the data source to tell the filter view controller what data it should display to be filtered.

Comment: for the the filterviewcontroller, do you think I should use a uitableviewcontroller or a pickerview? The problem is, the filter's value might expand depending on the setup of the user. eg. Skill FIlter might have 3 skills or 15 skills.

Comment: That's up to you, it becomes a styling question.  The advantage of the table view is that you can see more options at once without having to scroll.  So if you only had 6 options for example, the user could see them all right away and select the one she wants without having to scroll.  In the end the way the filters are displayed should be unrelated to the data source and the filter logic.  I would recommend you use custom data source and delegate protocols in your filterviewcontroller so that you can easily swap out the table view for a pickerview if you wanted.