# ios cocoa: How to adjust the size of the popover depending on the number of rows in uitableview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

This is related to this question

[ios filter options similar to the apple store (dropdown list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182736/ios-filter-options-similar-to-the-apple-store-dropdown-list)

I tried using a uitableviewcontroller instead of a pickerview as I couldn't understand how to use the picker view if I need it popping out (any info on it would be appreciated).

Now this is what I did.

I have a VC that calls out a "FilterVC". I only have one FilterVC that is called by 3 different "filter buttons", and I will just populate the VC depending on the button. The issue is, one button might have just 2 items that is needed to be shown, another one might containg up to 50. Was wondering how do I adjust the height of the popovercontroller that contains the uitableview? Also, is this the right way in dealing with popovers, 3 segues connected to one VC??? (It needed an anchor point)

Here's what it looks like

[image]

[image]

As a follow up question:
Is this the right way to do it on an ipad? I feel like most people prefer the uipicker. The guy that answered my first question said it's more of a design thing. Now since I'm no designer, as a user, do you think uitableview is more appealing?

Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view that you're showing in the popover, set `self.contentSizeForViewInPopover` as soon as you know the size and before the view is displayed.

The main benefit of using a table view over a picker is that it has a scroll indicator so you can see how long the list of options is. Also obviously that you can control exactly how the list is displayed. So the table view should be better if it fits in with your UI style and particularly if the list of options is long.

Comment: So how do I calculate how long the list is? I'm sure there's a default size for each cell. Not really sure how to grab that. Do I adjust it before the segue call? Or do I do that after the segue and when the viewdidload of the popovercontroller is executed?

Comment: The default is 44. But after the table view is loaded (viewDidLoad) you can set it to whatever you want with the rowHeight property. So long as you know what you're going to set it to and the number of rows you know the overall height.

Comment: viewdidload of the popovercontroller? Or the main viewcontroller where the popover is getting called from?

Comment: viewDidLoad of the view controller that is being displayed inside the popover controller

Comment: This method is deprecated in iOS 7

Comment: @LightningStryk, in iOS 7 use `preferredContentSize`